# Why is my Blender Game lighting the same regardless of where I put the light?

Tags: game-engine, light

I'm making a game in Blender Game Engine and I've come across another problem.

If I don't have any lighting at all when I go into game preview mode it shows up lit. This looks very cartoonish and messed up so I decide to put in lights. the problem is no matter what light I add and where (I could add a light 1000 miles from the thing I'm trying to light up) it always shows up like this.

[image]

This is even if the light is really far away from the object.

What is going on?

Comment: Do you have "Shadeless" checked on your materials? This disregards all light sources for a material.

Comment: please upload a .blend

Comment: @BillyS Sorry but i have no idea how to do that

Comment: Go here http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/.

Comment: Oh wait. what do i do now. it stopped doing that (as in my lights stopped going wonky)
. what do i do? do i del the question or leave it up.

Comment: If you know what the problem is, answer your own question.  If you don't, you might as well leave the question up. Maybe someone will come along and answer it.